# jinja2 error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2._compat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2, jinja2-cli

Trying to upgrade jinja2 to the latest stable version

Error according to the logs:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2._compat'`

Nothing related to this in the change logs https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/changes/#version-2-10

This is the sample code:

```
    from jinja2._compat import implements_to_string
    
    @implements_to_string
    def my_function():
        pass
```